# How to change background color of only one column using awk while converting csv to html

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have written `main.awk` and `color.awk` to convert CSV to html with conditional color coding.

Scripts are working but the problem is that, when condition is satisfied,it colors the entire row(all columns).

I just want to change the background color of corresponding column which is used to check condition and not the enitr row(not all columns).

command is run as below.

```
awk -f color.awk -f main.awk employee_data.csv >> employee_data.html
```

1)My color.awk is as below
here $1 is first column and depending upon value it returns the value of color to main.awk

```
function check() {
        if (( $1 = 8613)) return "green"
        if (( $1 > 8613)) return "red"
        if (( $1 < 8613)) return "red"
}
```

2) My main.awk is as below

main.awk calls check function to get color from color.awk using this line. color=check( ); Entire script is as below.

```
BEGIN{

FS="|"
  print "<html><body>"
  print "<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1>"
}

NR==1 {
  # Header row
  print "<tr>"

  for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
    print "<td><b>"$i"</b></td>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}

NR>1 {
  # Data rows
  print "<tr>"

  for ( i = 1; i < NF; i++ ) {

  color=check( );

print "<td bgcolor=\""color"\"><b><FONT  FACE=\"verdana\" SIZE=2>"$i"</b></FONT></td>"
#print "<td ><b><FONT  bgcolor=\""color"\" FACE=\"verdana\" SIZE=2>"$i"</b></FONT></td>"
}
  print "</tr>"

}
END {
  print "</table></body></html>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the check function hardcodes column 1, then in the for loop, instead of

```
color=check( );
```

you should do

```
color = i == i ? check() : "someDefaultColor"
```

Or, pass `i` to the check function (`check(i)`), and the check functions tests that the passed value is `1`.